# SSRS Display columns on top of each other

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

If I have a report that returns lets say 8 column as:

```
Col1 Col1 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8
```

Is there a way to have it display like:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8
```

The total number of columns will be variable, but I only want to show 4 on each row. Each Column should only return one value.

Comment: What do you mean by "the total number of columns will be variable"?  What would cause the number of columns to vary?  When I make a report in SSRS usually the column count is fixed and the row count varies.

Comment: It will basically be a column group. For example, if I create start date and end dates as parameters, and want to return activity from each day, if i put in 1/1/16 through 1/10/16, there would be 10 columns, one for each date. If i put in 1/1 through 1/20 that would be 20 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have 1 field to show for each date, then you can change the SQL query to map each field to the desired column and row.

Once you have calculated the row and column values you can use those values to group your data into the correct location (in my example it is total_sales).

```
DECLARE @data TABLE
(
    sale_date DATE,
    total_sales INT
)

INSERT INTO @data (sale_date, total_sales)
SELECT '2/1/2016', 100
UNION SELECT '2/2/2016', 450
UNION SELECT '2/3/2016', 175
UNION SELECT '2/4/2016', 900
UNION SELECT '2/5/2016', 150
UNION SELECT '2/6/2016', 425
UNION SELECT '2/7/2016', 300
UNION SELECT '2/8/2016', 550

DECLARE @date_from DATE = '2/1/2016'
    , @date_to DATE = '2/10/2016'

SELECT d.total_sales AS 'total_sales'
    , CONVERT(DATE, d.sale_date) AS 'sale_date'
    , (DATEDIFF(DAY, @date_from, d.sale_date) - DATEDIFF(DAY,@date_from, d.sale_date) % 4) / 4 AS 'Row'
    , DATEDIFF(DAY, @date_from, d.sale_date) % 4 AS 'column'
FROM @data d
WHERE d.sale_date >= @date_from
    AND d.sale_date <= @date_to
```

Sometimes it's easier to create a new matrix to display this data rather than try to manually alter the groupings in the old matrix.

- Add a new matrix
- Point the new matrix at your data set
- Map the 'total_sales' to the field marked 'Data' in the lower right
- Map the 'row' to the field marked 'Rows' in the lower left
- Map the 'column' to the field marked 'Columns' in the upper right